# Backbone get URL parameter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone js app that runs when I go to the URL `domain.com/item/1` or domain/item/2` etc.  When the app starts I create a new instance of my model and pass it an id which needs to be the last part of the URL.  Is there a way to access this in Backbone?

I know it's easy to build a router that can access parameters after a hash so I am better of changing my URL to be something like `domain.com/item/1#1`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you have a backbone router or not.But that's easily achievable by one of the basic use of `Backbone.router`.
and you do not have to use `#` or anything.You can access anything between slashes.

```
routes: {
  "item/:page":  function(page){
      //page holds the query parameter.
    }
}
```

> The routes hash maps URLs with parameters to functions on your router (or just direct function definitions, if you prefer), similar to the View's events hash. Routes can contain parameter parts, :param, which match a single URL component between slashes; and splat parts *splat, which can match any number of URL components. Part of a route can be made optional by surrounding it in parentheses (/:optional).

Please read the section of Backbone.router in the documentation for detail.

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

FYI, passing the query parameter to your model should not be executed when a user start app but when `routes` is called.otherwise everytime you want to change page,You need to change url and reload the whole page.

and usually Controller makes model instances which means,You'd better create controller instance with parameters in `router` and then create a model in the controller.something like this

```
routes: {
  "item/:page":  function(page){
      var page = new YourNameSpace.Controller.Foo({pageId : page});
      page.render();
    }
}

//inside of Itempage Controller
initialize : function(){
  this.model = new YourNameSpace.Model.Foo({pageId : this.pageId});
}
```